# VSP taxable capital gain, even when I didn't sell

Tags: canada, etf, capital-gains-tax

I have VSP (ETF) in a non registered Canadian account.   I am a Canadian resident and I am taxed there. I was surprised to see that I have to pay a capital gain tax on it because I hold shares, even though I didn't sell any.

What I see, but don't understand, is that there are [capital gain distributions](https://www.newswire.ca/news-releases/vanguard-investments-canada-announces-estimated-2020-annual-capital-gains-distributions-for-the-vanguard-etfs-r--866677714.html). Can someone explain what the difference between a capital gain distribution and a "regular" distribution is?

How can I find the expected (or last 5 years) capital gain distribution for my future investments? I want to reduce fees and tax.

Comment: related https://money.stackexchange.com/a/137300/13241